# count then insert else update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code and I'm trying to do a count and if(count) ==0 than insert else update.I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.The page should go to the next page if the query is done but the page only reloads and no data is inserted or updated.This action should be made when I press a button.Can you help me with this? I asked before but no answer.I tried now by my own but can't seem to see what is the problem.Sorry for repeating

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }


            String id_sesiune;
            id_sesiune = Session.SessionID;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=2",con);

            int read = Convert.ToInt16(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());


            if (read == 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'2',@ip,@idsesiune)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("User3.aspx");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }


            }

            else
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Raspunsuri SET raspuns=@raspuns,cod_numeric_personal=@cnp,data_raspuns=@data,id_intrebare=2,ip_user=@ip,id_sesiune=@idsesiune WHERE id_intrebare=2", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("User3.aspx");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Any exceptions? Does `SELECT count(*) from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=2` returns any rows?

Comment: if doesn't return I want to do the insert else the update..

Comment: if there is no rows return and step in to update section. It wouldn't throw error but there will no error and data inserted.

Comment: Your question is not clear, have you put this code in the button click handler? What SELECT query returns, are ther any exceptions/etc?

Comment: Yes..I putted in the button event and there no exception throwing..

Comment: i usually use LINQ so you folks can tell me if I am wrong, but is it a problem to be opening the same connection twice? and is it possible that the redirect is occurring before the page life cycle has enough time to complete the sql command? and you should put a  `con.Close()` before your redirect so you dont have open connections

Comment: did you step through it? try commenting out the execution code from if else block and see if it redirects you to other page.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 or better, take a look at [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), which was invented to solve this very problem.

Answer (score 3):

When I get caught in this kind of situations I will revert to a stored procedure.

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpsertRasPunsuri(@keyID int, @cnp int, @raspuns nvarchar(30),  
                     @data smalldatetime, @ip nvarchar(30), @idsesiune int)
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @cnt int
        SELECT @cnt = count(*) from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=@keyID 
        if @cnt = 0
            INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,2,@ip,@idsesiune)
        else
            UPDATE Raspunsuri SET  
                   raspuns=@raspuns,cod_numeric_personal=@cnp,data_raspuns=@data,  
                   id_intrebare=2,ip_user=@ip,id_sesiune=@idsesiune  
            WHERE id_intrebare=@keyID     
    END
```

now your code simplifies in this way

```cs
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString); 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpsertRasPunsuri",con);  
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyID", 2); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox2.Text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune); 
    con.Open(); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    Response.Redirect("User3.aspx"); 
} 

catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex); 
} 
finally 
{ 
    con.Close(); 
}
```

Of course I made a lot of assumptions here on your table, on the columns type and length.
However this will be relatively easy to accommodate. Now if you run your stored procedure from VS or SSMS you could rule out errors in the data access code.

Comment: but without a procedure?